# Javascript. Create multi dimensional array from calculation

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a multi dimensional array based off of the calculations of another 3D array.

Input array is in format [shift, start Num, end num]

I should be clear the "," is just for visual purposes. 
I need each value in its own array location i.e. `[value1]=location 0,0` `[value2]=location 0,1` `[value3]=location 0,2` etc.

Example:

```
aInput looks like this
[0,1,5]
[1,1,3]
[2,1,2]

aOutput should look like this
[1,1,1]
[1,1,2]
[1,2,1]
[1,2,2]
[1,3,1]
[1,3,2]
[2,1,1]
[2,1,2]
[2,2,1]
[2,2,2]
[2,3,1]
[2,3,2]
[1,3,2]
[3,1,1]
[3,1,2]
[3,2,1]
[3,2,2]
[3,3,1]
[3,3,2]
[etc]
```

It needs to increase the number of items in the array based on the shift. i.e 0 = shift would be 1 column, shift = 1 would be 2 columns, shift = 3 would be 3 columns, and so on. This is what I have so far, but I can not figure out how to make it calculate for anything with a shift.

```
var aInput = new Array();
aInput[0] = new Array("0", "1","5");
aInput[1] = new Array("1", "1","3");
aInput[2] = new Array("2", "1","2");

for (var x=0; x < aInput[x].length; x++){
    //Calculate out number
    if (aInput[x][0] == 0){ // Im sure this should be a loop of some sort, just not sure how to do it
        var i=Number(aInput[x][1]);
        while (i <= Number(aInput[x][2])){
            //Write to output array
            aOutput.push(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help, I'm really stumped on this one.

Comment: Sorry, could you please be more specific about the calculation algorithm? I can't really spot a pattern, and I don't get your input and output formats. Is it an example of three different inputs? Or is that actually an array of three arrays? What is [etc], I don't expect an infinite array?

Comment: Your question mentions a 3D array. Your input looks like a 2D array.

Comment: **I should be clear the "," is just for visual purposes. I need each value in its own array location i.e. [value1]=location 0,0 [value2]=location 0,1 [value3]=location 0,2 etc.

Comment: Is `myArr[1]` supposed to be `aInput[1]`? Do you mean `aInput = [[0, 1, 5], [1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 2]];`?

Comment: Input Format is [shift] [start number] [end number]

Comment: What does "shift" mean in this context?

Comment: Repeating things that you already wrote in the question doesn't make it any clearer.

Comment: Why is your loop comparing `x` to `aInput[x].length`?

Comment: Barmar - sorry myArray was typo. I fixed. Shift is how many columns should be in the array (base 0). Basically what I am doing is creating a counter loop that builds a grid of numbers. So if I have 2 "row's" in my array and the second is shifted to 1 then column 1 will duplicate until column 2 finishes the count then column 1 will move to the next number and the counter for column 2 will start over again.

Comment: Not really. Your first input has shift = 0. But the output array has 3 columns. How is that the number of columns that should be in the array?

Comment: Now I see it. Column 0 ranges from 1 to 5, column 1 ranges from 1 to 3, column 2 ranges from 1 to 2.

Comment: yes, correct and each range will count inside of each previous range so the above example would give you 30 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var aInput = new Array();
aInput[0] = new Array("0", "1", "5");
aInput[1] = new Array("1", "1", "3");
aInput[2] = new Array("2", "1", "2");

var input_indexed = [],
    elem = []; // elem holds the row to be added to the output

// Get aInput[] into a more useful arrangement
for (var i = 0; i < aInput.length; i++) {
    // Save the range of each column
    input_indexed[parseInt(aInput[i][0])] = {
        start: parseInt(aInput[i][1]),
        end: parseInt(aInput[i][2])
    };
    // Initialize elem with the start value of each column
    elem[aInput[i][0]] = parseInt(aInput[i][1]);
}

// Produce the output
aOutput = [];
done = false;
while (!done) {
    aOutput.push(elem.slice(0)); // push a copy of elem into result
    for (i = elem.length - 1;; i--) { // Increment elements from right to left
        if (i == -1) { // We've run out of columns
            done = true;
            break;
        }
        elem[i]++; // Increment the current column
        if (elem[i] <= input_indexed[i].end) {
            // If it doesn't overflow, we're done
            break;
        }
        // When it overflows, return to start value and loop around to next column
        elem[i] = input_indexed[i].start;
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/VQyr2/1/)

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much for your help. I am just trying to see how you did it exactly. You are breaking the input array into two separate arrays? I'm a little confused there. Sorry fairly new to JavaScript, if you do not have time to explain I understand and will just study this code more.

Comment: The original input had the column numbers as array elements. Since we need to look up the start and end values by column, I rearranged it into a new array where the columns are the indexes, and the start/end values are in the values. This is the `input_indexed` array.

Comment: This isn't even Javascript-specific. I would do the same thing in PHP, Perl, C, etc.

Comment: Yes, I was unaware you could index like that. That will help a lot in the future. So then if I am following correctly you are creating the range using the element array and then pushing that whole array into the aOutput?

Comment: I've added more comments to explain what it's doing.

Comment: So when I enter a second set of numbers to start from it looks like it overwrites the start values with the last start number for that column. For example if input array is: 
aInput[0] = new Array("0", "1", "5");
aInput[1] = new Array("1", "1", "3");
aInput[2] = new Array("0", "10", "20");
aInput[3] = new Array("1", "20", "30");
I never get the range [1-5],[1-3].

Comment: How can you have two different ranges for the same column?

Comment: It would be a second number set so I need to basically start over and add the second set to the bottom of the first set. This is because I will need to skip over ranges. In this example range 6-9 is not needed.

Comment: Replace the entire `aInput` and start again.

Comment: so something like if aInput[i][0] is less than aInput[i-1][0] then run what we have so far clear and then continue on?

Comment: There's no `if`, it's not part of the loop. Just run the whole thing multiple times with different `aInput`, but without initializing `aOutput` between them.

Comment: The array I will be getting as an input this will happen often. Can I push the column number to the elem array instead of setting the index with "aInput[i][0]"?

Comment: Doing this will require making `input_indexed` into a 2-dimensional array, where the second dimension is each range of that column. Then the loop that builds the output will have to be changed to keep track of which 2nd-dimension it's processing; when it overflows, it goes to the next range of that column, and only goes to the next column when it runs out of ranges. I'm not interested in writing this, I'll leave it for you. Once you're done, if it doesn't work you can post a new question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var aOutput = [];
for (var i in aInput) {
    var y = parseInt(aInput[i][1])
    for (var x = y; x <= parseInt(aInput[i][2]); x++) {
        aOutput.push([i, y, x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (var i in aInput)` is for objects, not arrays.

Comment: This looks like it is limited to 3 items across. I need something where the number of items across will expand based on how high the shift number is.